# How to automate getting an 'authorizationCode' from Google's OAuth 2.0 authentication system

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, karate

I am automating REST endpoints that rely on an 'authorizationCode' that you would typically get by running through the oAuth user consent flow provided by Google as described here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

My starting point to getting that 'authorizationCode' is a Google Auth URL that effectively loads the user consent flow in a browser.  eg https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=12345&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fblah.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com&access_type=offline&prompt=consent

I would like to see how people are solving this without manual intervention.  Reviewing 'OAuth Consent Screen' settings at console.developers.google.com doesn't elude to options to bypass the necessity to drive this UI to get an 'authorizationCode'.  I have found that you can set prompt=none but seems to only be an option if the user has previously authenticated through the user consent flow and doesn't require a new authorizationCode.

Appreciate any advice or suggestions.  Ideally if you could put this security flow into 'test mode' to enable automation akin to how you can put Re-Captcha into 'test mode' to avoid the challenge tiles.

Comment: If the browser page is a simple HTML form-submit, you can [simulate that in Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field) and that's what all the teams I know do. There is even an OAuth 2 sample in the demos: [`oauth2.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature). There are plenty of ways to extract information out of the response (either body, headers or cookies). I would be surprised if this is not possible. If you really can't find any solution, Karate has support for automating the Chrome browser directly so you could giv

Comment: Thank you for the sample.  So far we are unable to find a form exploring Google's implementation.  UI solution will not work for us as the server executing API automation will not have UI or Desktop experience just a terminal.

Comment: Why are you trying to automate this? It is a violation of privacy principles if you are able to obtain user data access without user consent.

Comment: I hear you.  I'm not looking to circumvent security defenses.  I'm just looking to test my APIs that rely on an 'authorizationCode'.  It would be great if Google allowed options to create test accounts, test authorizationCodes that are strictly for testing purposes.